# clickhouse table data size month wise

Tags: database, analytics, clickhouse

How to get the size of data pushed month wise in each of the table in clickhouse?

I tried exploring system.parts table in the clickhouse. I could not get much of the things from it if there is no partition made. Is there a way to get it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
partition,
min(min_time) AS from_date,
max(max_time) AS to_date,
table,
formatReadableSize(sum(data_uncompressed_bytes)) AS partition_size,
sum(rows) AS rows
```

FROM system.parts
WHERE (database = 'evagedemo') AND (table IN ['table_1', 'table_2', 'table_3'])
GROUP BY
partition,
table